# Windows 10: Can I disable window snap from mouse but NOT from keyboard?

Tags: windows, windows-10

I want to disable the window snap that triggers when you drag a window close to a screen edge (really annoying), but not the snap triggered by keyboard Win+Left etc shortcuts (really useful).

Under "Settings - Multitasking" there is an option to enable/disable snap. But despite the text there only mentioning mouse snap, it actually controls both versions.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can accomplish that through a registry edit.

1. Open the **Registry Editor** (by searching for it in the Start Menu, or press the <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> keyboard shortcut to open the Run box, and in the Run box enter `regedit` and press OK)
2. In the Registry Editor, go to the following location: `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop`
3. In that location find the key named ***DockMoving***. Double click it, and set its value to 0 (instead of 1)
4. Sign out, and then sign back into your system

Now, the mouse snap assist should not work, but the keyboard shortcuts should continue working.

[image]

Comment: That worked perfectly. Thank you.